# Why does a paragraph appear to the left of closed list?

Tags: html, css

I created a very simple HTML page which has a list and a paragraph. The problem is that the paragraph appears to the right of the list. If I create another paragraph, it is placed correctly. I would like the first one to show in the same manner.

```
<body>
  <ul>
    <li>(...)
    <li>(...)
    <li>(...)
    <li>(...)
  </ul>
  <p>This text is to the right of the list.</p>
  <p>This text is in a new line and is left-aligned.</p>
</body>
```

I don't refer to paragraphs anywhere in my CSS file and this is the part relating lists:

```
ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin 0;
}

li {
  float: left;
}
```

Comment: use `p {clear: both;}`

Comment: @Stilly.stack Your answer does not help. The only difference is everything moved to the very margins of the page. You mean putting reset before the paragraph?

Comment: What always baffles me is that people try to fix the elements __around__ the ones with `float`, instead of using the correct properties for `position`, `display` or `margin` on the culprit element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this

```
ul:after{
    content:'';
    display:table;
    clear:both;
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/6a9kF/)

This has to be done whenever you use floats. Best practice is to make a class like this -->

```
.clearfix:after{
    content:'';
        display:table;
        clear:both;
}
```

and add this class to the parent block if the child is floated .Always try to follow this step.

For more detailed explanation refer this link -- > http://www.impressivewebs.com/clearing-floats-why-necessary/

Answer (score 2):

Don't use `float: *;` if you don't know what the floating an element does. `float` takes an element out of the normal flow. However, you want to show the `li` on a single line without loosing their `display: block;` properties. That's exactly what `display:inline-block;` is for ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/WH4uR/1/)):

```
ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin 0;
}

li {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: Personally, I prefer the `display:inline-block;` too

Answer (score 1):

### **[See it in action HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/salota8550/WH4uR/)**

The code

HTML

```
<body>
  <ul>
    <li>(...)</li>
    <li>(...)</li>
    <li>(...)</li>
  </ul>
  <p>This text is to the right of the list.</p>
  <p>This text is in a new line and is left-aligned.</p>
</body>
```

CSS

```
ul {
    list-style: none;
    margin 0;
    padding: 0;
}

li {
  float: left;
  margin-right:10px;
}
li:last-child{
  margin-right:0;
}
p{
    clear: both;
}
```

Explanation:

you need to add `clear:both` to your paragraph `<p></p>` elements.

in `ul{...}` we set the `margin` & `padding` to `0`

in `li{...}` we give some space between the `li` items by giving `margin` of `10px` to the right.

in `li:last-child{...}` we removed the `margin-right:10px` & set it to `0` because it is the last item in the `li` list.

Comment: So where did the explanation go? :-)

Comment: it's is there now,, I was updating it... sorry for that.